# What's the English idiom/phrase for insisting on/talking about/bringing up the same subject (equivalent of "drilling one's head")?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, translation, popular-refrains

In Arabic (Specifically, north-western Levantine), there's a saying that goes like

> He **drilled my head** about/with that lunch meeting (**بخشلي راسي** باجتماع الغدا)

Which means something along the lines of

> He kept insisting on/talking about/remind me of/bringing up that lunch meeting

It can be used in situations where your girlfriend wants you to take her out somewhere and she keeps reminding you about it everyday, when your kid keeps asking for a new bike everyday, or when your boss keeps bringing up that report you have due next Monday.

The saying doesn't carry the connotation of negligence reluctance on behalf of the person on the receiving end. The person might or might not be working on fulfilling his promise or adhering to the other party's wishes.

Many times I find myself in such situations and I really need something to use. I often use the direct translation as written in the first example.

**Is there an equivalent for that in English?**

<sup>The closest thing I was able to think of was "nagging", but it doesn't convey how strongly I feel about the situation.</sup>

Comment: Nagging was the first thing to come to my mind; could you please clarify what's unsatisfactory about it?

Comment: "Drill into someone's head" is an English expression that Arabic had borrowed/imported. It is already an expression used in English ever since there had been drills.

Comment: "Drill into someone's head" has a slightly different meaning in English - it's more about making someone learn or remember (e.g.  old-fashioned school teaching), and any implied frustration is typically from the person with the teaching role towards the person who won't learn without endless repetition. This is asking for a stronger way of getting across the frustration of *being* excessively nagged, esp to do (not learn) something. [edit - Just noticed kaviseigel already posted about this below](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/156743/23300)

Comment: "*Nagging*" is a fairly strong and pretty derogatory term in English.  It's not the kind of thing that you would want your boss or your spouse to hear you say about them.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Likewise I wouldn't want someone drilling in my head, figurative or not, or hearing about it.

Comment: Are you looking for some specific dialect of English (e.g. British/American/Canadian/Australian/etc.)?

Comment: immune to nonsense

Comment: Having read only the title before reading the question, my first thought was along the lines of "trepanation"/"trephination". Never mind, nothing to see here, carry on!

Comment: It sounds like "nagging" or "bugging" or "bringing up" or "going on and on and on" would perhaps be close to equivalent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A very common American English expression is *beat over the head*.

He **beat me over the head** about that lunch meeting.

Comment: I've been in the US my whole life (mid-Atlantic) and I've actually never heard this phrase used this way (although if I *did* hear it I would probably be able to figure it out through context).

Comment: @JasonC How odd; lived in the same region (almost) my whole life, and I’ve heard it plenty of times.

Comment: Yes, I grew up in the mid-West and mid-Atlantic and have heard it frequently.  Also in books, TV, movies.

Comment: Now that I think about it I *have* heard this phrase, but to mean something more along the lines of "rubbing it in", or yelling at somebody for a mistake (especially revealing a mistake when a person thought they either didn't make one, or got away with it).  Almost always in context of failure. I did find one reference to [its definition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/hit-over-the-head) (see example). Weird though, I wonder why I seem to be in a bubble of not hearing this phrase that much.

Comment: NE USA : I hear it often.

Comment: Also, I don't think Alice would "beat Bob over the head *about* it". She would "beat Bob over the head *with* it", which makes more sense when "it" is a failure on Bob's part or some other existing fact, rather than something Alice is trying to get Bob to do.

Comment: Curious: Did this come from 'browbeat'? Or browbeat come from this phrase maybe?

Comment: @Peeja nevertheless, the commonly used preposition is *about*. Preposition usage in English doesn't make much sense. You just have to memorize the phrases.

Comment: @sgroves Is it? My point was that it isn't. I don't know that I've ever heard someone phrase it that way before. (MA, USA)

Comment: It certainly is. You beat someone over the head *with* an object, but *about* an issue.

Answer (score 41):

At @ermanen 's suggestion, I will promote this suggestion from a comment:

*to harp on about* something is to continually refer to that thing to an annoying degree.

There's a discussion here: http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1544 about the origin of the phrase suggesting it originally alluded to playing the same string (on a harp) monotonously.

*to bang on* probably derives from a similar musical metaphor.

Comment: Harp on and bang on are both good - but also simply "go on about it". (Or "go on and on" for something stronger.)

Answer (score 28):

Also, *wouldn't drop the subject.*

Or even, a less polite, *wouldn't shut up about it.*

They both mean about what you've said.

Comment: Similar, colloquial: "[Bob] keeps *banging on* about [that lunchtime meeting]".  Particularly if it's someone giving you grief about something that happened in the past. (quite common expression in UK, don't know about elsewhere)

Comment: "keep _harping on_ about" works the same.

Comment: @Neil: I think you should write that as an answer because that is the best one so far. It is an idiom also.

Comment: "banging on", and to a lesser extent "harping on", are British usage. They're almost unknown in the US ("banging on" has more of a sexual connotation).

Comment: "running one's mouth about" or "ramble about", "be on one's case about", "hassle/ badger/ nag/ pester someone about" might work

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps *`to pester`*?

Which, according to Collins dictionary [word definition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pester), comes quite close to `nagging`, meaning: *`to annoy or nag continually`*

Comment: I was going to post nagging +1

Comment: I think this word is strong enough to be used by one about to develop a headache as a result of being constantly nagged.

Answer (score 13):

Here a a couple more:

1) **Badger**

> to harass or urge persistently; pester; nag: I had to badger him into
>   coming with us. ([dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/badger))

2) **sounding like a broken record**

> someone or something that annoyingly repeats itself, as a vinyl record
>   with a scratch ([dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/broken+record?s=t))

Example:

> You are starting to sound like a broken record.

Comment: "Badger" doesn't fit: it mostly means to make persistent and irritating demands, not just to repeatedly bring up the same subject. You can badger somebody to repay money they owe you, but not badger them about your team beating their team in the match last week.

Comment: IMO, given the context of the OP, `badger` is quite appropriate.

Answer (score 12):

Colloquially, you could use:

> Chewed my ear off.

Comment: I think this is generally related to talking too much. It does not connote repeating and insisting on the same thing.

Comment: @ermanen it would if you added about: _chewed my ear off about his kids_ for example.

Comment: @terdon: In my opinion, still does not count. It can still mean talking too much about kids but not repeating the same thing about the kids. Well, you can mean that in the context as well but there are better answers that fits to the definition.

Comment: I'll side with ermanen and terdon on this one. Chewing one's ear off involves talking incessantly about a topic, but does not imply the nagging reminder that drilling describes.

Answer (score 9):

Another common colloquial phrase that seems to mean the same thing is "Wouldn't let it go."

Answer (score 5):

"[To hound](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hound)" (verb), as in, "he kept hounding me about that project he wanted done"?

Answer (score 4):

*"Pecking my head"* == nagging or pestering, especially in an irritating continuous manner.

I'm having some trouble finding a decent definition or good sources for this phrase, but it's common slang especially around Manchester in the North of the UK.

Comment: As a British native speaker who grew up within 40 miles of Manchester, I've never heard "pecking my head". This  suggests it may be very localized to Manchester or rather recent.

Comment: I grew up in Rossendale, Lancashire; about 30 miles north of Manchester and this phrase was well known there.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'd also say this in Liverpool.

Comment: To be more precise, my 40 miles was to the east, in West Yorkshire.  Must be a Lanky thing!

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best equivalent is "grilled". Saying "He grilled me about that meeting" would be a standard English way of saying the person (who presumably wasn't there) was peppering you with questions in a very one-sided effort to get information out of you. It doesn't imply you were cooperative with providing information, nor does it imply you were uncooperative. It does imply the person didn't really care which it was.

Comment: I was thinking "grilled" as well, although it may be a bit too neutral for the OPs tastes (at least, the way I use it it doesn't necessarily imply that the event was an annoyance or a negative experience).

Comment: "Grilling" only applies to repeated requests for information, which isn't a scenario mentioned in the question. For example, constantly reminding somebody that they performed badly in some situation wouldn't be grilling.

Comment: Definitely NOT grilled. To grill is to _ask_ (demand) repeatedly for information, in a harsh or unfriendly manner.

Comment: Inappropriate, as explained.

Comment: In UK usage "grilled" doesn't necessarily imply repetition - just intensive, difficult questioning. For example "I saw a great interview on Newsnight last night, the host Paxman gave that politician a real grilling"

Comment: @user568458 - It doesn't imply repetition in the US either. This is why I don't have much patience with folks who quote dictionary passages at me. There's inevitably some important shade of meaning the dictionary misses or gets wrong. Its important to remember that dictionaries are attempts to be *descriptive*, not *proscriptive*.

Answer (score 4):

How about [bending my ear](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bend_someone%27s_ear).

I don't know how widely this colloquialism is used, but it certainly matches your specifications.

Comment: I'm not sure that Wiktionary definition is correct. I thought that phrase meant “get your attention,” as in “May I bend your ear with this idea I have?”

Comment: Australian slang also allows for "pissing in my ear" - which is the same thing, but when it's annoying for the listener (as well as being a fun phrase).

Comment: I have never heard this phrase in American English; is this a common phrase in the UK (I see references to it in British English on the internet)?

Comment: It's a phrase I'm familiar with from my youth (I'm 53) and I still hear it used. However I don't know how widely used it is in the UK. @BraddSzonye it definitely does not mean just *get your attention*. I have only heard it used to mean someone is ranting at you.

Comment: I've heard it used (and use it occasionally myself) here in the UK.  It definitely does NOT mean ranting in my experience. It's more a "can I have a quick word?" type phrase with the implication that it'll be a lot longer than just a quick word.

Comment: I'd largely concur with @Grhm. It's a phrase I've heard and used occasionally in the UK, more so in my youth (1960's, 70's).  The connotation is usually a "telling off" and may in some way be related to pulling someone forcibly to one side by grabbing their ear prior to giving the telling off.  I's say it's more typically a one-off event than a "banging on" that the OP was after.

Comment: @BraddSzonye - agreed. Wiktionary doesn't sound right to me (NE USA).

Answer (score 3):

The literal translation of that is a phrase I've used and have heard tossed around before..

> He drilled it into my head at lunch

or

> The teacher drilled this equation into my head

I suppose that means more of taught, or causing memorization instead of the nagging you're describing, which is slightly more negative.

Depending on what he was saying at lunch:

> - He harassed me about it over lunch (or teased)
> - She continually insisted we go out to that expensive French place
> - The kid has been campaigning for this new video game for weeks now

Comment: "Drilled into me", from military style _drills_ where you do something over and over until you can do it with your eyes closed.

Answer (score 3):

I think the English saying that comes close is **beating a dead horse**.

> So you would use this to say:
>
> Mark kept going and going.  We already told him we weren't interested
>   but he kept **beating a dead horse**.

Comment: Normally, beating a dead horse has the implication that the one-sided discussion is pointless because the situation is already decided (generally on the opposite side of the case being argued.)   I don't see that connotation in the idiom in the question.

Comment: Given your definition @Beska it is right on target.  They don't want to hear anymore because they have already decided (for or against).  Either way (even for) they don't want to keep hearing the same points - beating a dead horse.  If they haven't decided then you are open for discussion.

Comment: I disagree.  The original question doesn't say anything about the situation being resolved in the listener's mind one way or the other or at all.  The listener may or may not be decided, and the situation, in particular may be unresolved.  This is not the case with "beating a dead horse".

Comment: @Beska - I use this phrase exactly how the user describes.  Sorry if you think different.

Comment: I also agree that "beating a dead horse" isn't really appropriate. It generally refers to past events that cannot be changed, especially where "should have" can be used (e.g. continuously criticizing something for something they already did) rather than potential future events (e.g. continuously asking for a bicycle). A more appropriate usage for the bicycle example would be if a child wanted a specific bicycle that he saw in a store but the father did not purchase it and the opportunity passed (think "should have" bought the bicycle), yet the child continued to pine over it.

Comment: "Beating a dead horse" is a [recent American version](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beating+a+dead+horse%2Cflogging+a+dead+horse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeating%20a%20dead%20horse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflogging%20a%20dead%20horse%3B%2Cc0) of the [British original](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beating+a+dead+horse%2Cflogging+a+dead+horse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeating%20a%20dead%20horse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflogging%20a%20dead%20horse%3B%2Cc0) ***flogging***.

Comment: Inappropriate, as explained by @Beska.

Answer (score 3):

Americans don't use it much (yet?), but in recent decades Brits have become increasingly fond of...

> *"You're [**doing my head in**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doing%20my%20head%20in&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,doing%20my%20head%20in;,c0) [always asking for that new bike!]"*

Where in *my* vernacular, that "supplementary clause" would probably be phrased as *"...keep banging on about that new bike"*. It's important to note that the usage is extremely "slangy", and dismissive of the person you're accusing of bothering you. It's certainly not an appropriate thing to say to the boss at work who keeps asking you for an overdue report (unless you want a new job! :)

Comment: I was going to say "Kept banging on about ..." but I'm not sure if that's too much of a UK-centric colloquialism.

Comment: @Grhm: Yeah - definitely *our* vernacular (British). The ["prevalence" values in NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=banging+on+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbanging%20on%20about%3B%2Cc0) are at least 5 times higher on the UK corpus than the US one. And doubtless the US ones will include *their* editions of Harry Potter books, for example - which I'd bet are bound to include the expression several times.

Comment: -1 - borderline vulgar.

Comment: @comeAndGo: [Cambridge Advanced](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PDHCFSRmjSMC&pg=PA664&dq=%22doing+my+head+in%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XP0gU_mwEbST0QWg84HQDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22doing%20my%20head%20in%22&f=false) says *UK/AU  informal*. "Vulgar" is a broad definition, which can include saying *toilet* or *loo* instead of *lavatory*. But it's a relatively rare new usage in AmE, so I expect mostly it doesn't have much of a classification apart from being something those coarse Aussies say when they're not effing and blinding.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I said "borderline" - it's crude slang - sounds like high school lingo - not something a refined person would generally use, particularly in a public/business context.

Comment: @comeAndGo: I think building site rather than high school - but yes, I did say "not to be used when talking to the boss".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - _- but yes, I did say..._ - True. Since you specified such, edit the post and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: "Doing my head in" really means "driving me crazy". There's an implication that whatever activity that's threatening to result in a one-way ticket to la-la land is constant or repeated, but it doesn't refer specifically to the inability to shut up about a topic. Buying a batch off lemonade cans with ring pulls that snap off without properly opening the drink might do your head in.

Answer (score 3):

She was getting on your nerves. After searching for that online for a reference.

[http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/get-on-(one's)-nerves](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/get-on-%28one%27s%29-nerves)

Turned up. Which mentions bug.

> She was bugging you. If she was using real bugs this would itch a lot.
>   Maybe not as bad as drilling your head but still uncomfortable.

The thesaurus helps in finding stronger alternatives.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/bugging 
http://thesaurus.com/browse/bugging

> I'd select vex, chafe, abrade or pester as strongly worded
>   alternatives.

Comment: IMO `bug` is excellent.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

> banging on about

or

> going on about

E.g *your girlfriend keeps banging on about taking her out somewhere*, or *your kid keeps going on about a new bike*.

But these tend to have a connotation that the person is harping on about something that they shouldn't - the message has been received, and they ought to stop haranguing you about it. I'm not sure it works quite as well with the boss/report example - even if you're doing all you can to get the report done.

Comment: "Banging on" not so much in American English, but "going on" is common and seems like a more global safe bet. Also in AE, "rattling on". Still, all of these seem milder than what the OP is looking for, to me they suggest "background noise" that is mostly ignored/dismissed rather than something that is actively irritating the listener.

Answer (score 3):

The terms "riding" and "off my back" and "on my back" come to mind.

e.g. If my wife was constantly telling me or asking me to get the taxes done I might say to her "Quit riding me about the taxes!" or "Get off my back about the taxes!" or "You're always on my back about the taxes!"

I might complain to someone else about her, saying "She keeps riding me about the taxes!" or "She won't get off my back!" or "She's always on my back to do the taxes!"

However, these phrases would not usually be used when speaking to a child, in my opinion.
Nagging or pestering, as previously mentioned, would be fairly strong and common words for your scenario to use with adults and children.

Answer (score 3):

He kept harping on that lunch meeting.

He wouldn't let that lunch meeting go.

He refused to drop the lunch meeting.

He kept going on and on about that lunch meeting.

He kept grilling me about that lunch meeting.

Answer (score 2):

How about: 
`He got on my nerves with this lunch meeting`? I'm not a native speaker, but this seems to me the easiest way :)

Comment: "He got on my nerves during the lunch meeting." - This would make more sense if you were speaking to someone.

Comment: as I understood, its not during the meeting, but talking about it

Comment: You would still use "He got" vs "He went"

Comment: ah okay, sorry didnt saw that :)

Comment: He "got on my tits" is a similar one, indicating annoyance with the other person, but I wouldn't suggest using it. It seems to be a phrase that is used exclusively by males.

Comment: Present "He is getting on my nerves about this lunch meeting."

Answer (score 2):

Nobody has mentioned my personal favourite:

> Giving me earache

Answer (score 2):

He kept *dredging up* that lunch meeting.

Comment: In what sense?  Dredging is the act of digging at the bottom of a river or harbor.  You don't dredge up as a stand alone.  You can dredge up a topic, bad memories, etc.  Perhaps you meant drudging up?  Making a drudgery of the meeting.

Comment: As you said, he kept dredging up the topic, the topic being the lunch meeting, or anything else the listener would prefer to leave alone, like the mud on the river bottom.

Comment: I guess I didn't parse it that way.

Answer (score 2):

How about the simple and possibly less exciting term "Going on about", as in:

```
He kept going on about that lunch meeting.
```

Or the slightly more exasperated:

```
He kept going on and on about that lunch meeting.
```

Answer (score 1):

How about "**rambled on (and on)**"?

Of course, that would be for the idea of one session of such "drilling".  It doesn't convey that there would be/have been more than one session of such.

For that, you would want to use "**keeps rambling on and on about**".

Hope that helps.

Comment: Or “*droned* on (and on)” when tedious/repetitive/boring.

Comment: Rambling/droning on implies talking in a long-winded way; the question seems to be asking about repeatedly bringing up the subject. If I talk to you for 20 minutes about something, I'm rambling/droning on; if I talk to you about it 20 times a day, I'm ________.

Comment: Rambling (also droning/going/banging/rattling/etc.) all seem milder than what the OP is looking for, to me they suggest "background noise" that is mostly ignored, or met with dismissive eye-rolling, rather than something that is actively irritating the listener.

Answer (score 1):

A close equivalent is the Englssh idiom **"Put a bug in your ear"** - meaning to remind or scold as unpleasantly as having an insect in the ear would be.

Answer (score 1):

I do like the phrase

> He rabbited on about

According to [this](http://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Slang/R/rabbit_on_1570.htm) it comes from 'rabbit and pork' which is English rhyming slang for 'talk'.

Comment: Apparently colloquial British English - never heard it used in the USA. Perhaps explain this...

Comment: @comeAndGo Cockney rhyming slang. Look it up, you will find some pretty amusing examples!

Comment: @DavidM - I'm certain I would... :) Cockney is one of my favorite "dialects" - that and "Brooklynese", my mother tongue...

Comment: @comeAndGo Brooklynese is literally mine, too. My mother and father are both from Brooklyn. Although, my father, in a bid to improve his business-credibility spent years losing his accent. And, hence I was raised (on Long Island) with a very nondescript accent.

Comment: _in a bid to improve his business-credibility_ - ROFLMAO Luckily I am in a business where it doesn't matter! Actually, I see he did source `rabbited` with that link.

Answer (score 1):

He has a [bee in his bonnet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bee_in_one%27s_bonnet) about that lunch meeting.

The "bee in his bonnet" idiom implies that he talks about that meeting to everyone, whether or not they are interested in that meeting.
It implies that at least some people are not as obsessed with that meeting as he is.

Answer (score 0):

In some circumstances, 'harangued' would work.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I heard `ripping one's ears off`.

Comment: This answer could be more helpful if you tell us more about why you think this is a good alternative. For example, you could explain what the phrase means and provide an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`Pounding` or `Pummeling` are often used colloquialisms (at least in NE USA) for such a thing - as if to say `pounding with questions`:

```
  He kept pounding (or pummeling) me about that lunch meeting.
```

Answer (score 0):

One phrase that I've heard sometimes is "He **drilled** me about..." and it has the connotations of pestering someone with questions and discussions about something. That was the phrase that popped into my head since it is similar to "Drilled my head about..."

Answer (score 0):

In our friend circle, we had/have a term and an expletive is used when saying it and we used it only amongst us.

Head-.... , the expletive starts with f.

A few members  were called by a nickname Chronic head ....... , the expletive starts with f.

Answer (score -1):

A less formal: ***"doing my swede in"***

Comment: -1 : Colloquial with no source whatsoever. Never heard it used in NE USA or seen it any American source (actually I don't think I've ever seen or heard it at all, and I have traveled a good deal.)

Comment: I've heard this in Liverpool, UK. Swede = head, i.e. "doing my head in".

Answer (score -4):

You could say that he *picked your brain*

From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pick_someone%27s_brain):

> (idiomatic) To seek information from someone knowledgeable; to ask questions of someone.
>
> *After I spent a couple of hours picking his brain, his scheme started to make sense.*

Comment: That phrase is more for asking for information about someone else's expertise (not nagging), and it's usually positive not negative. "Can I pick your brain about X?" is both a question and a small compliment - "I respect your expertise on X, will you share some with me?". "Bob was picking my brain about X" wouldn't imply that Bob was annoying me, it'd imply that Bob was asking questions about something that I think I'm an expert on (and, it'd also imply that I have a high opinion of my expertise on X... so people usually talk about picking other people's brains).

Answer (score -4):

You could also say "he picked his brain"

Comment: Usually this is used when the asker is asking for extremely detailed information; it doesn't necessarily imply repetition or a negative experience.

Comment: This is incorrect, as explained. _brain picking_ means extracting useful information from some sort of subject matter expert.